# Unable to push "git-tfs" cloned code to remote origin

Tags: git, azure-devops, tfs, git-tfs

I have to migrate the code from TFS to Azure DevOpsService Git repository. For that, I am using "git-tfs". The cloning of tfs code using "tfs-git" is ok. However, when I tried to push the code to remote origin, I am facing the issue. I tried the following approaches -

1. In an empty folder, I did `git init`, then `git clone <remote Git>`. After that, I ran `git tfs clone <TFS-url> <TFS folder`. I removed the traces of "Config" and "Description" files inside `.git/` repository (just removed the references of . When I tried to push the code by executing `git remote add origin <remote Git Url>` and `git push –u origin –-all`, I got the error like `Outer clone contains inned clone. Do you want to create submodule?` I can understand that because in the folder, cloned from TFS, there is already a '.git' folder. Instead of that, I tried normal `git add .`, `git commit` and `git push`, I got the response as "everything is up-to-date" but nothing is really pushed to remote origin.
2. Second, I tried with another empty folder. I did `git init` but did not clone from the remote origin. Then I cloned the TFS code from TFS server using "git-tfs". This time, there was no 'outer clone', so I thought everything would be smooth. However, as I did `git init`, so there was a `.git` folder already created. Again, I got the same error.
3. I tried again by taking a fresh directory. I did not do `git init`. I even cloned the TFS code in a different directory and then copied to the empty directory. After setting the origin, when I executed `git push –u origin –-all`, I got the message that `Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind. Use git pull before pushing again.` When I tried `get pull`, I got the message, `fatal:regusing to merge unrelated histories`.
   How to fix the issue ?

Comment: You should not init a git repository, 'git tfs clone' is doing it for you. After, you need to add the remote and push. See https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/usecases/migrate_tfs_to_git.md After you should push. But depending how the ADO repo has been created (if one commit with a README.MD for example), you will have to force push.

Comment: @user1748546 May I know any updates? Can you resolve the issue by following my below answer?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, the problem is that there is already a `'.git'` folder in the repository. There's a `config` file in the `'.git'` folder which defines the version control information (includes the original remote repo there) initialized by the [git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs) tool.

So, we need to remove the original remote repo and other `git-tfs` settings from the `config` file first, then run `git remote add origin <remote Git Url>` to set the new git remote.

Try to follow below steps to do that:

1. Create a directory where TFS code to be migrated to
   (`git-tfs-demo-repo` in below sample).
2. Open terminal in administrative privilege and cd to the newly
   created directory in terminal.
3. Run below command to clone the TFS repo

   `git tfs clone https://{server-Name}/{Collection} $/ProjectName/xx`

   A new repo is created in the directory (`TFVC` repo for example here).
   [image]
4. Open `config` file with any text editor from directory `.git` of
   newly created repository directory.
   The original `config` file should like this:

   [image]
5. Remove all sections except the `[core]` section from the `config`
   file, then save it. So, the `config` file would look like this:

   [image]
6. Run below commands to set git remote and push to remote repo.

   `git remote add origin <remote Git Url>`

   `git push –u origin –-all`
7. Once completed, we can see the `config` file changed to look like
   this: (version control is changed to the new remote repo)

   [image]

Screenshot for your reference:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-from-tfvc?view=azure-devops

This will allow you to keep history from your TFSVC repo in your new git repo.

Comment: If 6 months of history and only 1 branch migrated is enough...

Comment: Yes, as Phillippe pointed out, max 180 days history we can get from Azure DevOps service import wizard

Comment: wow. what a shitty product.. I'm so sorry you people have to use ADO